# max-width should be overriding width, but doesn't

Tags: html, css, width

I've checked documentation on multiple sites, and they all agree that `max-width` should be overriding `width` in CSS. For some reason, though, it's always staying at 800px. This is my CSS:

```
.content{
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This should be making it stay at 800px wide unless the window gets smaller, and then shrink it, right? I also tried the other way around:

```
.content{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

This gives me the same result. It's always 800px, no matter what. I had thought of using `min()`, but it turns out that was removed from CSS (though why, I have no idea). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I should point out that I have included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in my header. That has no effect.

Comment: The css is working in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vu2ra588/).. Maybe there are some other factors or styles affecting it..

Answer (score 0):

You must know that the device-width maybe larger than 800px, if ti's larger than 800px, so your max-width:100%, will not work unless some other wider dom than 800px distract the wrapper.